# How do I create a prisma migration with a dictionary data?

Tags: prisma

I have some dictionary table in my DB schema. E.g. "EventType" whth fields "id" and "value".

This table have one row:

```
1    TypeOne
```

Can I create a prisma migration with sql?

```
INSERT INTO "EventType" (id, value) VALUES (2, 'TypeTwo')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the prisma migration files are *valid SQL* so you can put any arbitrary SQL in your migration files and it will be added to your migration history.

This is what you have to do:

1. Generate a new migration *without applying it to the database* with the `--create-only` flag.

```
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only
```

2. Take a look at the generated `migration.sql` file and update it accordingly to add any new SQL statements.
3. Apply the migrations `npx prisma migrate dev`

**Important Note**: Always make sure you apply the changes to `migration.sql` *before* applying it to your database. Modifying an already applied migration file will lead to a corrupt migration history.